# Error Message: [webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: webpack, solidity, webpack-dev-server, decentralized-applications, webpack-cli

I am working on blockchain project and whenever I try to run "npm run dapp"

I get the following error:

[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options has an unknown property 'stats'. These
  properties are valid:
  object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

I am using webpack: 5.71.0 webpack-cli: 4.9.2 webpack-dev-server 4.8.1

My webpack.config.json file is as follows

```
**const path = require('path')
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
        static: {
          directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/'),
        },
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: '/dist/'
        },
        port: 3000,
        hot: "only"
    }
}
**
```

```
I was expecting dapp application to run and give me webinterface. on http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: This specific issue was resolved after following the migration guide of webpack from v3 to v4:

Comment: Now my webpack.config.dapp.js file section named "devServer" is update as per below:
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dapp"),
    port: 8000,
    devMiddleware: {
    stats: "minimal",
    },

Answer (score 0):

This specific issue was resolved after following the migration guide of webpack from v3 to v4.
Now my webpack.config.dapp.js file section named "devServer" is update as per below:
devServer: {
static: path.join(__dirname, "dapp"),
port: 8000,
devMiddleware: { stats: "minimal",
},